# Customising Spring Boot Exception Handling to Prevent Stacktraces Being Returned in Rest Response

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception, error-handling

How do I configure my spring boot service so that errors such as 500 don't potentially leak implementation details such as stacktraces.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019/05/01 15:06:17",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.ed25519.Ed25519LittleEndianEncoding]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.math.ed25519.Ed25519LittleEndianEncoding and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->........)",
  "path": "/api/test"
}
```

**Note:** here the stacktrace is in the `message` and not the `exception` part of the json.

As you can see I am already formatting the timestamp with:

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

  private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
  private static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, boolean includeStackTrace) {

    //Let Spring handle the error first
    Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace);

    //Format & update timestamp
    Object timestamp = errorAttributes.get(TIMESTAMP);
    if(timestamp == null) {
      errorAttributes.put(TIMESTAMP, dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    } else {
      errorAttributes.put(TIMESTAMP, dateFormat.format((Date)timestamp));
    }

    return errorAttributes;
  }
}
```

But I need to handle the message too.

If this 500 was the only error I could just do:

```
errorAttributes.put("message", "Server error. Contact support.");
```

However, all the errors go through here and that would override all the messages.

I could check if the status is 500 and only modify it then. However, there are other errors that can be generated that also might leak stacktraces.

Using `@RestControllerAdvice` seems to require knowing every exception that is generated and having an `@ExceptionHandler` for each and knowing which status code to respond with.

Is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the "cleanest" approach, but with projects I've been on we had a "standard format" for our Error Responses across projects, so we had a custom object with the fields that matched our orgs standard (HttpStatus, Reason, ect.) that extended RuntimeException. Then in our controllers, services, repos, ect we would catch exceptions and create this object accordingly and throw the custom one up instead. Based upon where it happened in the app (repo, service, controller, ect.) we could give our own custom verbage to it, but still log out the full exception in our server logs so we could investigate later

For example if we caught an error in our repository we would create our custom error object, set the Reason to DB unavailable (really all the consumer needs to know), set the status to HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE (we tracked these with reasons and httpstatus with enums to keep status the same across modules), and throw the custom object up to the controller to be returned.

Sorry if this was a longwinded answer that may not give you what you want, I'm not too familiar with how you're trying to do it so figured I'd just give an example of other methods. I'll put some sample code as well

Custom Exception:

```
data class MyException(
    val reason: String,
    val httpStatus: HttpStatus? = null
) : RuntimeException(reason)
```

Method for creation:

```
fun createApiException(errorCode: ErrorCodeEnum) = MyException(
    reason = errorCode.reason,
    httpStatus = errorCode.httpStatus,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Spring-boot** provides us with a standard method to handle exceptions using spring aop concept. You can use the `@ControllerAdvice` and `@Exceptionhandled` annotations to handle exceptions from a spring-boot rest endpoint so that a custom exception is always thrown from a rest endpoint with proper error code and error response.

The `@ResponseStatus()` annotation can be used to customize the response code being thrown.
For example consider the custom exception :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

  public DataNotFoundException(String exception) {
    super(exception);
  }

}
```

We can throw this error from a rest GET mapping when a data is not found like :

```
  @GetMapping("/trains/{id}")
  public Resource<Student> retrieveTrains(@PathVariable long id) {
    Optional<Trains> trains = trainRepository.findById(id);

    if (!train.isPresent())
      throw new DataNotFoundException("id-" + id);

    Resource<Trains> resource = new Resource<Trains>(train.get());

    ControllerLinkBuilder linkTo = linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).retrieveAllTrains());

    resource.add(linkTo.withRel("all-trains"));

    return resource;
  }
```

**Default error response** provided by Spring Boot contains all the details that are typically needed.

However, you might want to create a framework independent response structure for your organization. In that case, you can define a specific error response structure.
For example :

```
public class ErrorDetails {
  private Date timestamp;
  private String message;
  private String details;

  public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
    super();
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
  }
```

To use this error node we use :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(DataNotFoundException.class)
  public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleUserNotFoundException(DataNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
        request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
```

- `@ExceptionHandler(DataNotFoundException.class)` indicates that this
  method would handle exceptions of the specific type.
- `new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` - Create an
  error response object and return it with a specific Http Status.

For a **more generalized exception handler** you can define a method that handles exception of the type **Exception.class**, **that way you don't have to know every exception**.

Like :

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
  ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
      request.getDescription(false));
  return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Reference from : https://www.javaguides.net/2019/02/spring-boot-2-angular-7-crud-example-tutorial.html